# Grails installing REST client plugin

Tags: rest, grails

I'm trying to start fresh a new project with rest calls.
I downloaded the 'http-builder-helper' https://github.com/bobbywarner/grails-http-builder-helper, then I tried the command 'grails install' and I get this error :

```
Task 'install' is ambiguous in root project 'http-builder-helper'
```

| Grails Version: 3.0.9
| JVM Version: 1.7.0_79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your dependencies:

`compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-http-builder-helper:1.0.0"`

If it does not work, add maven repo for bintray as below:

`repositories { maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/bobbywarner/grails-plugins" } }`

You can look into [this issue](https://github.com/bobbywarner/grails-http-builder-helper/issues/22) for more information.

If your options are open, you can try [rest client](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rest-client-builder) based on spring rest template. To add this into your application, use

`Compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:4.0.7.RELEASE"`